# Azure Powershell Function App Interacting with Blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

Very new to Azure and Function Apps.

I'm trying to set up a simple Function app using Powershell which needs to read the content from a blob (simple .txt file), do some simple processing on it and write a copy of that file into different blob.

So far I have set up the integration on the app, which I can see provides a binding I can use. Looks like this:

```
 {
  "name": "inputBlob",
  "direction": "in",
  "type": "blob",
  "path": "input/logs.txt",
  "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
}
```

I'm referencing that binding in the powershell params at the start of the script:

```
# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata, $inputBlob)
```

As I understand things this should allow me to connect to that blob and interact with it. What I don't understand is how should that be done? I have tried to use the cmdlet that seems to make the most sense for the situation:  Get-AzStorageBlobContent

for example:

```
$blobContent = Get-AzStorageBlobContent -name $inputBlob
```

But when I try to return that content in my http reponse (so I can check that it was read), the response body is empty.

I presume that I will need to add further bindings for outputing to blobs too?

For example, the Set-AzStorageBlobContent  cmdlet seems to only support 'files' but in my case within the function app, I don't have a file, just a string or an array, so how do I push that content into the target blob?

Would appreciate any pointers on how to achieve this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$inputBlob` variable should contain the blob data as an array of bytes, so you can do:

```
foreach ($value in $inputBlob) { ... }
```

or anything else you would do with an array of bytes.

If you need to output to a blob, you need to add an output binding:

```
    {
      "name": "myOutputBlob",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "output/data.txt",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
      "direction": "out"
    }
```

and push the data to this binding from your function code:

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name myOutputBlob -Value 'my value'
```

Comment: Fantastic. Works brilliantly. Thank you!